# Search through Users with dynamic attributes with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

.Hi i'm working with Asp and SQL-Server and i have no problem with writing dynamic query

I'm trying to Write a search page for searching people.

I have 3 related tables:
See my table diagram in : http://tinypic.com/r/21159go/5

What i'm trying to do is to design a search page that a person can search users with a dynamic number of attributes.

Example:
think that a username called "User1" has 3 attributes named "Attr1", "Attr2" and "Attr3" related to him in "UserAttributes" table and "User2" has 3 attributes named "Attr1", "Attr2" and "Attr4".
Attribute names and other bunch of items unrelated to search function saved in "Attributes" Table. This is because i want to relate an attribute between multiple users. and their values are stored in "UserAttributes" table.
Well someone wants to search upon "Attr1" and "Attr2" and wants to return all users that have "Attr1" and "Attr2" with specific value.

I need a query to know how to implement this. I can write a dynamic query with asp.net so if someone please give me a query for this one example i have brought, i would be thankful

P.S. This is not my real database. my real database is much more complex and has more fields and tables but i just cut it and brought only necessary items. and because attributes are very dynamic they can't be embedded in table columns.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That could be solved as a Relational Division problem. But most people would recommend against an [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model) design.

Comment: Take a look at Linq to Sql, this provides a elegant way to define your where clause from your app. You could also use Lucene to generate a more queryable index from your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your DB diagram your code would be something like this

**update:**

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserAttributes AS ua1
    ON u.USER_ID = ua1.USER_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserAttributes AS ua2
    ON u.USER_ID = ua2.USER_ID
WHERE (
        ua1.attribute_id = 'att1'
        AND ua.attribute_value = 'MyValue' )
    AND (
        ua2.attribute_id = 'att2'
        AND ua.attribute_value = 'MyValue2' )
```

In where clause you would specify the attirbute_Id and what value you are expecting out of it.  Than just decide if you want to restrict users to have all values match or just one of them, in that case modify `AND` between statements to be `OR`

- if you just want to do this quick and dirty you can create your own class library that can create adhoc sql that will pass to the database.
- if you want more organized matter, create SP that will bring back users and accepts any left of id and value. Do a lot of that by passing list separated by comma, colon or semicolon. Than split it up in SP and filter results based on those values
- there are many other alternatives like EntityFramework, LINQ-to-SQL and other options, just need to figure out what works best for you, how much time you want to spend on it and how easy will it be to support later.

Comment: I have tried that but didn't work. Because attribute_id has to be both equal to att1 and att2 and that's not possible. and OR doesn't work also because it returns all the attributes that have atleast one match . but i need to match all of the rows. anyway i tried using Count function with OR and filtered it with number of matched attributes. it worked but i didn't like the solution because maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: Sorry got a little confused, because you are trying to check two different attributes at the same time you need to join to that table twice. Try the query that I have now, that should work.